# Call C++ dll from C# dll and get nothing

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am developing a C# dll for Revit(a software for Civil Engineering), and the C# dll calls the function from unmanaged C++ dll that was developed by myself. When the function **compareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel_** in the unmanaged C++ dll is called, nothing is got, it seems that the function in the unmanaged C++ dll does not execute.

---

**Here are the details:**

---

in the unmanaged C++ dll

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void compareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel_(
char* a_,
const double* list,
int listLength) {

std::vector<std::vector<double>> b; 
for (int i = 0; i < listLength / 6; i++)
{
    std::vector<double> cc;
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        cc.push_back(list[i * 6 + j]);
    }
    b.push_back(cc);
}

std::string a = a_; 

CompareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel cmpb(a, b);
cmpb.readMarkedPoint3DInfo();
cmpb.computeAB();
cmpb.computeRT();
cmpb.computeDeviation();
system("pause");
```

}

in the C# dll

```
[DllImport("Test_OpenCV.dll")]
    public static extern void compareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel_(
        string st1,             
        ref double list_,     
        int listLength_);       

    public Result Execute(
        ExternalCommandData commandData,
        ref string messages,
        ElementSet elements)
    {                       
        string smallImagesPath =        
            "C:/D/Bundler04ForReconstruction/results/result_DF510";            
        double[] list;
        int listLength;
        setList1(out list, out listLength);           

        compareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel_(
            smallImagesPath,
            ref list[0],
            listLength);

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }        

    public void setList1(out double[] list, out int listLength)
    {
        /// realize of the function         

    }
```

---

I have searched the Internet for solutions, but got no useful solutions.
I have also tried to call the unmanaged C++ dll (especially the function) in a C# console project, and it works! It is strange.
Also, the platforms for the unmanaged C++ dll and C# dll are all x64.
So, why the function not execute, is there anything wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an exception? Is the unmanaged DLL using COM? If so, call it in a MTA thread (just run it in a background task), since it's working in a console application, this might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. No exception was got, and maybe COM is not used because it is new thing for me. So, should I try MTA thread as you advised?

Comment: Yes, try to run it in a Task or explicit MTA Thread. If it works on console but not on UI project, that may be the issue.

Comment: I have tried to run it in a Task Thread and MTA Thread, but it does not work in both of the two thread. The result is still that the function is not executed and no exception is thrown. Could anything else result in the phenomenon?

Comment: How about removing system("pause");? That call doesn't seem right in a non-console application.

Comment: If you are not able to enter the unmanaged DLL using a debugger, try to write out debug info to a file to check where the execution stops.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to remove  system("pause"); before posting the topic, but it did not work. In the unmanaged DLL, I define a function and use the function to write the log info into a file as you advised, while all the other code has not been changed. This time, the function compareMarkedPointsWithBIMModel_ works. It is strange! I just add some code about log.